# Ratchet WAMP onpublish always publish to all clients include the publish caller or not?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, autobahn

I have just made a chat hello world for the Ratchet WAMP + autobahn version 1.
[full source code here if you want to see](https://bitbucket.org/jasper2virtual/wamp_chatserver1/src)

The JavaScript client send chat message:

> ```
>            function click_send_btn() {
>                  var json_data = {
>                     "message": $.trim($("#input_message").val())
>                  };
>             sess.publish("send_message", json_data, true);
>             }
> ```

The PHP Ratchet server publish the message:

> ```
> public function onPublish(\Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
>     switch ($topic) {
>         case 'http://localhost/enter_room':
>             $foundChater = $this->allChater[$conn];
>             $newChaterName = $event['username'];
>             $foundChater->setChatName($newChaterName);
>             break;
>         case 'send_message':
>             $foundChater = $this->allChater[$conn];
>             $event['username']=$foundChater->getChatName();
>             break;
>     }
>     $topic->broadcast($event);
>     echo "onPublish {$conn->resourceId}\n";
> }
> ```

[image]

I don't understand why publish with excludeme not working.
In the above 2 firefox, right firefox said: I am bar. The message should not display at himself, but it is.

[doc ref: autobahn version 1 javascript publish with excludeme](http://autobahn.ws/js/reference_wampv1.html#id3)

[doc ref: ratchet onpublish](http://socketo.me/api/class-Ratchet.Wamp.WampServerInterface.html#_onPublish)

[doc ref: ratchet topic broadcast](http://socketo.me/api/class-Ratchet.Wamp.Topic.html#_broadcast)

Comment: Maybe Ratchet does not support the option. Btw: whats wrong with Thruway + Crossbar?

Comment: Hello Mr oberstet, I haven't try them yet, try them tomorrow. thanks a lot. Ha ha, maybe you remember me in another post of PHP server RPC..... Anyway, if not limited to PHP, which server you can suggest will work best with Crossbar? will http://tavendo.com/ have a project of WAMP server?

Comment: oh, i just found your sample now https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/twisted/wamp/beginner/server.py

Comment: Crossbar supports multiple languages for creating application components: http://crossbar.io/docs/Choose-your-Weapon/. The code example you linked above is for people who want to implement their own _router_ - which you don't need (since there is Crossbar).

Comment: Maybe it's not clear enough: you don't need another "server" besides Crossbar. Crossbar will _host_ (and monitor) your app components, and does directly serve clients (for WebSocket, and also static Web assets - if you want).

Comment: I guess Ratchet is support the excludeme, i just var_dump the array $exclude, it does show correct excluded sessionId, my code not working because I haven't handle it, instead , i use the broadcast. I will try to find the other solution asap, eg. connection->event function , but i have to leave now, my office is close.

Answer (score 1):

I have just fix it.
What a fool I am. I had not handle the parameter "array $exclude"
and I also used the $topic->broadcast($event) to force broadcast to all.
Now I create a function

> ```
> /**
>  * check whitelist and blacklist
>  * 
>  * @param array of sessionId $exclude -- blacklist
>  * @param array of sessionId $eligible -- whitelist
>  * @return array of \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface
>  */
> ```

```
private function getPublishFinalList(array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    //array of sessionId
    $allSessionId = array();
    $this->allChater->rewind();
    while ($this->allChater->valid()) {
        array_push($allSessionId, $this->allChater->current()->WAMP->sessionId);
        $this->allChater->next();
    }

    //if whitelist exist, use whitelist to filter
    if (count($eligible) > 0) {
        $allSessionId = array_intersect($allSessionId, $eligible);
    }

    //then if blacklist exist, use blacklist to filter
    if (count($exclude) > 0) {
        $allSessionId = array_diff($allSessionId, $exclude);
    }

    //return array of connection        
    $result = array();
    $this->allChater->rewind();
    while ($this->allChater->valid()) {
        $currentConn = $this->allChater->current();
        if (in_array($currentConn->WAMP->sessionId, $allSessionId)) {
            array_push($result, $currentConn);
        }
        $this->allChater->next();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

in the onPublish, I not use the $topic->broadcast($event) anymore.

> ```
>     $conn2PublishArray = $this->getPublishFinalList($exclude, $eligible);
>     foreach ($conn2PublishArray as $conn2Publish) {
>         $conn2Publish->event($topic, $new_event);
>     }
> ```

connection class has a method 'even', which can send message to the 'subscriber' directly.
[Ratchet.Wamp.WampConnection event method](http://socketo.me/api/class-Ratchet.Wamp.WampConnection.html#_event)